# Something similar to relplot and displot for plotting boxplot with Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

In Seaborn [relplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) and [displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html), there are setting called `col_wrap` that  enable multiple axes arrayed in a grid of rows and columns that correspond to levels of variable.

While the `relplot` having the option to `plot` `scatter` and `line`, the `displot` have the option to plot `hist`, `kde`, `ecdf`.

Currently, I have to rely on the following code to plot grid of rows and columns that correspond to levels of variable

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
variables=['Lunch','Dinner']
for i, c in enumerate(variables, 1):
    filter_ch = tips ["time"].isin ( [c] )
    dv = tips [filter_ch].reset_index ( drop=True )
    plt.subplot(2,1,i)
    g = sns.boxplot(x='sex', y="total_bill",hue='day',data=dv)


plt.show()
```

I have search the net for something similar to `relplot` and `displot` for plotting `boxplot`, but to no avail. Should such approach exist, really appreciate if someone can direct me to the appropriate material.

Also, is there more compact and proper way than using the above proposed code since in actual practice, the `variables` will be more than two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the trick is to use [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)

```
sns.catplot(data=tips, x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="day", col="time", kind="box",col_wrap=1)
```